# Adding an Expression to a Range in the Excel COUNTIF Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Simple question that will likely end in me using a different function, but not entirely sure what would do the same command with an expression added to the comparison.

Here is my simple function:

```
=COUNTIF('Service Calls'!E:E,C3)
```

This will return if an exact match is found, however it is querying a time column that holds hours and minutes. What I want to pull is only the whole hour so that I can collect service calls per hour. How would I go about running the `COUNTIF` function with an added modifier such as `HOUR()` for each cell in the comparison? I could right this in code very quickly, but for some reason my brain goes blank when it comes to excel.

I have tried this, but obviously this will never work:

```
=COUNTIF(HOUR('Service Calls'!E:E),C3)
```

Any thoughts or direction would be great! Thanks guys and gals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=sumproduct(--(hour('Service Calls'!E:E)=C3), sign(len('Service Calls'!E:E)))
```

The [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) does not like thrown errors so if some of your data cannot have the HOUR stripped out of it, additional error control will have to be added.

SUMPRODUCT will calculate every cell you tell it to. It does not not truncate full column references to the extents of the data like a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). Be wary about using full column references with SUMPRODUCT; always pare down the cell ranges to a reasonable approximation of the actual scope of the data.

If your data strictly 'holds hours and minutes' then this may be more appropriate (and more efficient).

```
=countifs('Service Calls'!E:E, ">="&time(C3, 0, 0), 'Service Calls'!E:E, "<"&time(C3+1, 0, 0))
```

This COUNTIFS solution is not appropriate with datetime values but the SUMPRODUCT will peel out the hour of values containing both a date and time.

Comment: That is an awesome function! It did not work for mine though because I believe the range has to be converted to a list first for that one to work. Comes back with the `#value` response in the cell. I tried a few variation, one of which returned a positive count on EVERY cell in the range. Ha.

Comment: The value in C3 has to be a true number between 0 and 23. If it is text, then the HOUR resolves as 0 which is why the blank cells were showing false positive. I've adjusted the SUMPRODUCT to discount blank cells and made a notation warning against using full column references.

Comment: I see. It will also resolve as 0 if the cell is blank correct?

Comment: If C3 is blank then Yes it resolves as zero hour (e.g. between midnight and 00:59:59 AM). The addition of the check for a length of a value in 'Service Calls'!E:E discards any blanks from the count.

Comment: That is the issue I have run into at this point because it is based on a survey tracker that has blank rows until new data is input. My end goal is to make it a funny independent system that does not require user updates (extending the ranges) other than the data input by the survey.

Comment: The second `COUNTIFS` function worked perfectly! I did not know you could add less than or greater than to the statement!